# nifi asking for signin after installation

Tags: apache-nifi

[image]

[image]

after running nifi i'm facing signin issue as unauthorized. in commandline it is saying failed to determine the process. can some one please help with the installation

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Nifi-1-14-asks-for-username-and-password-on-Windows/td-p/320966

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use NiFi 1.6.0 - this is from April 2018.

Please consider using NiFi 1.15.3 which is the latest release and includes the work for the recent log4j vulnerability.

With 1.15.3, security is enabled by default, which includes TLS and authentication.

When you start NiFi, you will instead access `https://localhost:8443` and be presented with a proper login form. The Username/Password of an initial admin user will be printed into the nifi-app.log as:

```
Generated Username [USERNAME]
Generated Password [PASSWORD]
```

Comment: still i'm facing the issue 
``` ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Self-Signed Certificate Generation Failed java.io.IOException: exception encrypting data - java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size``` and nifi is getting stopped.

Comment: This is a different issue. Did you install 1.15.3 to a clean directory?

Comment: @user15437862 also try a new JDK update, later than 1.8u252 - your u141 is  from 2017